# How to use searching method using a select tag option to search id,email,username in PHP, MYSQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, search

Hello I'm trying to get a searching method using select tag with an option of ID,Email, and Fullname.

I have this html code for search:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
<select class="searchoptionuser" name="Search" id="searchbyuser">
<option value="" disabled selected value>Search User</option>
<option value="ID">ID</option>
<option value="Email">Email</option>
<option value="Fullname">Fullname</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." id="search_text" class="searchtext">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

And I want to filter the search when I select the ID, the search will only search by ID and also Email and Fullname.

I've tried this in PHP:

```
<?php
include "includes/connection.php";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if(isset($_POST['Search']) == "ID")
{
// query code here from database
alert(1);

} else if(isset($_POST['Search']) == "Email") {
// query code here from database

} else if(isset($_POST['Search']) == "Fullname") {
// query code here from database
$output = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' or lastname LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$output .= "<tr><th>User ID</th><th>Email</th><th>Fullname</th><th>Phone Number</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$output .= "<tr>
<td>" .$row["id"]. "</td><td>" .$row["email"]. "</td><td>" .$row["lastname"]. ", " .$row["firstname"]. "</td><td>" .$row["phonenumber"]. "</td>
</tr>";
}
echo $output;
} else {
echo "No account found.";
}
}
}

?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. Is this possible in php or this method is only for javascript or jquery. Please help anyone. Thanks

Comment: You could start with investigate what is being posted:  print_r($_POST); exit(); Then you should remove alert(1) - that is not php code.

Comment: I see a couple of mistakes here, first of all you have 2 form elements with tha same name `search` which will result in only one of them being passed to the php script and then in your ifs you use `if(isset($_POST['Search']) == "Fullname")` where you should be using `if($_POST['Search'] == "Fullname")`. Finally your code is vulnerable to sql injections you should be using prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a conditional query based on the data you get from $_POST.

```
$query = "";

if($_POST['Search'] == "ID")
{
  $query .= "AND firstname LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' or lastname LIKE '%".$_POST["Search"]."%'"";
} else if($_POST['Search'] == "Email") {
  $query .= "AND email LIKE '%".$_POST["Search"]."%'";
} else if($_POST['Search'] == "Fullname") {
  $query .= "AND ID = ".$_POST["Search"];
 }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1=1 ".$query ;
```

Please ignore syntax errors if any as I have not tested the code but it will give you an idea how you can achieve it.